# Image is not fit to the frame of UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview

I am creating the `UIImageView` using interface Builder. Its frame size is (320,67).
I want to display the image on the imageView. I am getting the image from the web. The problem is that the image get from web is stretched to display on the imageview...
Here my code

```
NSData *imageData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.isco.com/webproductimages/appBnr/bnr1.jpg"]];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Can anyone tel me that how to display the image fit to display on imageView????

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Either use

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

or

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

The first one will fill the frame, possibly cutting off parts of your image. The second one will show the entire image, possibly leaving areas of the frame open.

Comment: Swift3 is now imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit or .scaleAspectFill

Answer (score 7):

**For Swift :**

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
```

**For Objective-C :**

```
 imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit
```

*ScaleAspectFit option is use to scale the content to fit the size of the view by maintaining the aspect ratio. Any remaining areas of the view’s bounds is transparent.*

[image: Screenshot]

Refer [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewContentMode) for details.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up resizing the image after the image was scaled according to it's aspect ratio.

```
let widthRatio = ImageView.bounds.size.width / (captureImageView.image?.size.width)!
let heightRatio = ImageView.bounds.size.height / (captureImageView.image?.size.height)!
let scale = min(widthRatio, heightRatio)
let imageWidth = scale * (ImageView.image?.size.width)!
let imageHeight = scale * (ImageView.image?.size.height)!
ImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
imView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```