# How to align an image inside a imageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I wanted to know how to align an image to the right while keeping the aspect fill. So this is how my image view looks right now.

[image]

I would like to move the image to the left, so that the image looks like this.

[image]

Now I tried aligning it to the right, but the image is so big that it only shows her gun. So I was wondering how would you be able to do this. Would I have to use a ScrollView? Would appreciate the help, Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436178/image-is-not-fit-to-the-frame-of-uiimageview check it .

Comment: Set the ‘.contentMode’ to aspect fit.

Comment: set image content mode aspectfit  yourimageview.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

Comment: Yes, you will have to use `scrollView` if you don't want to use `.scaleAspectFit` property as it will cut the part of the image if not in same ratio of your `imageView`.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this works for you or not:

Try the different `contentModes`:

Use it like:

```
imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit //Or any from below options
```

You can Use **StoryBoard** also:

[image]

[image][image][image]

Try different types which suites your **useCase**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Set **Content Mode** of image Which is best for you Image View.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could resize imageview as per the image size, below code is not tested:

```
CGSize kMaxImageViewSize = {.width = 100, .height = 100};
CGSize imageSize = image.size;
CGFloat aspectRatio = imageSize.width / imageSize.height;
CGRect frame = imageView.frame;
if (kMaxImageViewSize.width / aspectRatio <= kMaxImageViewSize.height) 
{
    frame.size.width = kMaxImageViewSize.width;
    frame.size.height = frame.size.width / aspectRatio;
} 
else 
{
    frame.size.height = kMaxImageViewSize.height;
    frame.size.width = frame.size.height * aspectRatio;
}
imageView.frame = frame;
```